# Disable errors when getting postal code using ipapi.co

Tags: php, location, ip

I'm retrieving the postal code by using -

```
<?php $pstcde = file_get_contents('https://ipapi.co/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/postal/'); ?>
```

It works great but if the postal code is not found, it says, "None".  I can't find a way to disable the message.

Comment: nothing in this code would perform output. file_get_contents() **RETURNS** whatever it fetched. it will not get echoed unless YOU do the echoing yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can empty the variable if the respond is `None`. With a simple check.

```
<?php 
  $pstcde = file_get_contents('https://ipapi.co/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/postal/'); 
  if($pstcde === "None") 
      $pstcde = ""; //Empty string. Or you can use unset($pstcde); if you want to unset the variable.
?>
```

Comment: The if worked.  Thank You.